# WPF - Is there a way to convert a url in a bound string to a clickable link

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have the following datagrid:

```
            <DataGrid
            Name="dgTaskList"
            MinHeight="60"
            Padding="5"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            Background="White"
            BorderBrush="#FFD1DCE6"
            GridLinesVisibility="None"
            HeadersVisibility="None"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ValidationResults}"
            RowHeaderWidth="0"
            st:StackPanel.Fill="Fill">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image
                                x:Name="Img"
                                Width="24"
                                Height="24"
                                Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="information">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Img" Property="Source" Value="/SHDHubApp;component/Images/information.png" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="warning">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Img" Property="Source" Value="/SHDHubApp;component/Images/warning.png" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="fail">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Img" Property="Source" Value="/SHDHubApp;component/Images/fail.png" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding FormatString}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
                            <Setter Property="Panel.Margin" Value="5,0,0,5" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

The second column is bound to the 'FormatString' property, this is usually a string but this string can sometimes contain a URL, for instance:

- Row 1: This task can take a substantial time
- Row 2: For guidance please visit [www.help.com](http://www.help.com)

what i need to do is somehow make the link in the second row clickable, but this is always variable so there may be a clickable link in non, all or some of the rows.

Is there a way to automatically convert the url in the string to a clickable link?

Comment: You can use a DataGridTemplateColumn that contains a TextBlock and use an IValueConverter to compose the content of inline text elements and inline a [Hyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.hyperlink?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#examples)

Comment: However, be aware that the Inlines property is read-only. You can not directly bind it. The workaround is an attached property or a derived TextBlock with a bindable Inlines property. You could also derive a TextBlock that directly understands your FormatString and updates its Inlines accordingly.

Comment: Automatically? No.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>                
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="StartValues"
CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource StartValuesCellTemplateSelector}"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>

<contr:StartValuesCellTemplateSelector x:Key="StartValuesCellTemplateSelector">
        <contr:StartValuesCellTemplateSelector.dataTemplatOne>
            <DataTemplate>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=YourTextValue}"/>
                             
            </DataTemplate>
        </contr:StartValuesCellTemplateSelector.dataTemplatOne>

        <contr:StartValuesCellTemplateSelector.dataTemplatTwo>
            <DataTemplate>

               <TextBlock>
                     <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding YourTextValue}">
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=YourTextValue}" />
                     </Hyperlink>
               </TextBlock>
                             
</DataTemplate>
        </contr:StartValuesCellTemplateSelector.dataTemplatTwo>
    </contr:StartValuesCellTemplateSelector>

public class StartValuesCellTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item != null && item is ValidationResultsModel itemContext)
        {
```

//-----------------------

```
            switch (itemContext.TemplateId)
            {
                case 1:
                    return dataTemplatOne;
                case 2:
                    return dataTemplatTwo;
            }
```

OR

```
if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(itemContext.YourTextValue, UriKind.Absolute))
  return dataTemplatTwo;
 else 
  return dataTemplatOne;
```

//-----------------------

```
        }
        return null;
    }
    public DataTemplate dataTemplatOne { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate dataTemplatTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This ignores the fact that the field content is a composition of normal and hyperlink text, and should hence be visualized by an InlineCollection. Two different DataTemplates are no solution here.

Comment: Ohh sorry, there you need yours own Usercontrol derived from TextBlock, You had true

Comment: That is also not exactly true. A UserControl is not derived from TextBlock. And you do not necessarily need to derive a control at all. An attached property applied to a TextBlock would also work.

Comment: I mean Usercontrol as your own Control,) i prefer behaviours for that purposes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).